# Nullability of generic type in Action<T>

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I have the following code:

```cs
public class Maybe<T>
{
    private readonly T? _value;

    public Maybe(T? value) => _value = value;

    public void WhenNotNull(Action<T> func)
    {
        if (_value != null)
            func(_value);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    void DoSomething<T>(Maybe<T> s)
    {
        s.WhenNotNull(TestMethod);
    }

    private void TestMethod<T>([DisallowNull] T x) => Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
}
```

Now `s.WhenNotNull(TestMethod);` generates

> warning CS8622: Nullability of reference types in type of parameter '`x`' of '`void Test.TestMethod<T>(T x)`' doesn't match the target delegate '`Action<T>`' (possibly because of nullability attributes)

There is no way for the parameter to be null, is there any way to signal this to the compiler?
NB: If the Maybe object is concrete (eg. `Maybe<string>`), this warning is not generated.

Comment: You can use generic constraint `where T: notnull` to tell the compiler it will not be null.

Comment: Aren't you just reinventing `Nullable<T>`?

Comment: @nbokmans Tried that on the `Maybe<T>` type, but no success, using `void DoSomething<T>(Maybe<T> s) where T: notnull` works though, thanks.

Comment: As nbokmans says, you can change your declaration of `DoSomething<T>(Maybe<T> s)` to: `public void DoSomething<T>(Maybe<T> s) where T: notnull` - then it will compile without warnings.

Comment: Also: If you add `: notnull` to the `void TestMethod<T>(T x)` method, you can remove the `[DisallowNull]` from it since it is no longer required (it essentially implies the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

The `Action<T>` delegate is defined as follow:

```
public delegate void Action<in T>(T obj);
```

You can define your own delegate which includes the `DisallowNull` attribute:

```
public delegate void MyAction<T>([DisallowNull] T x);
```

If you now change `WhenNotNull` to use `MyAction<T>` instead of `Action<T>`, the warning will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the signature of DoSomething to include where T: notnull

`public void DoSomething<T>(Maybe<T> s) where T: notnull`

Credit to @nbokmans and @Matthew Watson.